# Goal flow requirement not being enforced

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I've created a custom goal in Google Analytics with a required Funnel step 1--and the required step 1 is not being enforced.

1. The custom goal has type "Destination"
2. Destination "Begins with"
3. Funnel "on"
4. Step 1 required "on"

Picture of problem: http://www.iibayarea.org/wp-content/themes/institute/resources/ScreenShot-1.png

When viewing the goal flow section of the reporting tab, Step 1 has less total sessions by source than step 2--which should be impossible. I can also clearly see in the visualization section of the Goal Flow report, sessions are flowing directly from sources to the destination step 2, without going through step 1--in short, the step 1 requirement is not being enforced.

Picture of problem: http://www.iibayarea.org/wp-content/themes/institute/resources/ScreenShot-2.png

This is causing my goal completion number to be artificially inflated (~2000%)

I have three other goals with Funnel requirements that are being properly enforced. I cannot see anything different about this one.

Any suggestions for correcting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my own question here: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2008/06/25/funnel-problems-google-analytics/#sr=so&m=r&cp=(sfgfssbm)&ct=/rvftujpot/11630325/hpphmf-bobmzujdt-hpbmt-xspoh-fousbodft-boe-fyjut-jo-gvoofm-tmc&ts=1408644836

Basically, when creating a goal, requiring a step *only affects the funnel visualization report. It doesn't affect any other report--including goal completions*.

As far as I can tell, you cannot require a step for purposes of goal completions. As long as someone navigates to the destination page, it is counted as a completion. It doesn't matter how they got there.